# Добавление сайта на сервер Denwer

Tags: denwer, сервер

Установил локальный сервер - Denwer. Хочу добавить сайт wg.com. Он не открылся. Установленный test1.ru открывается, а мой нет. Помогите! Как его установить?

Я уже смог его открыть по адресу: www.wg.com. Как его открыть по адресу: wg.com?

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы сайт был доступен из локальной сети, тогда вам нужно настраивать всё совершенно по-другому. Но это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Я пробую, но все равно не открываеться! Открываеться настоящий сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте **README** файлы.
В структуру виртуального диска (который вы создали) добавить ветку директорий (*папки*):
*имя диска*:\home\wg.com\www\
И в него разместить коды (index.php и т.д.)

Comment: Я пробую, но все равно не открываеться! Открываеться настоящий сайт.

Comment: Вы точно перезагружали Denwer ? Не может такого быть, потому, что локальный сайт имеет приоритет :)

Comment: Да, открылся! Но по адресу www.wg.com

Как сделать что бы открылся по адресу wg.com

Comment: попробуйте почистить кэш, незнаю.  
Денвер автоматически перенаправляет в **www** для него _http://www.wg.com_ и _http://wg.com_ одно и тоже

Comment: А если в hosts поменять местами www.wg.com и wg.com ? Видимо браузер (или чем Вы сайт открываете) после установления соединения вызывает getpeername(), а потом gethostbyaddr(). Ну и для IP 127.0.0.1 получает первую строку.

Comment: Пробовал, не чего не меняется!

Answer (score 0):

Создайте текстовой файл с названием ".htaccess" в www директории и в него вставьте этот текст:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.wg\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wg.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Для того чтобы ваш сайт работал создайте около него то есть около localhost и test1.ru папку wg.com и в нем создайте папку www затем перезапустите Денвер то есть Stop и Start и так два раза при этом закройте все браузеры! и все будет хорошо!

Да и чуть не забыл в созданный каталог(C:/WebServers/home/wg.com/www/) закиньте файл index.php и в нем:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';
```

Comment: Что за извращения _Stop и Start_ есть и **Restart**

Comment: Я пробую, но все равно не открываеться! Открываеться настоящий сайт.

Comment: Браузеры закрывали?

Comment: Если и все равно не работает. Есть ручной метод как в фильме Армагеддон где русский сломает с космическом корабле рычаг. Заходим в (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) затем в блокноте открываем файл hosts и добавляем след. строки:

127.0.0.1 www.wg.com

127.0.0.1 wg.com

Comment: Пробуем...

Comment: Да, открылся! Но по адресу www.wg.com

Как сделать что бы открылся по адресу wg.com

Comment: А вы какой адрес ставите браузеру? wg.com или http://wg.com?. Если первый, то попробуйте второй, с указанием протокола (а то браузеры шибко умные)

Comment: Пробовал и так и так. Ничего!

Comment: "Есть ручной метод как в фильме Армагеддон где русский сломает с космическом корабле рычаг" - эта что ваапсче за бред? О_о

Самая обычная процедура, причем не только под форточками